# Issues with partitions WIN 7

Tags: windows-7, boot, partitioning

I was trying to make some space to install linux in my HP notebook.
The computer had 4 partitions, I made space shrinking one and created a new one (facepalm) using the windows partitioning tool. It show me some warning message saying something about dynamic partitions, I ingored it, and went to the linux live CD.
I installed linux in the new partition, after the installation completed it told me that GRUB cannot be installed I dont remember why.

So now, it doesnt boot, neither windows nor linux.
After google for a while I found the diskpart command, it gives me this info:

```
DISKPART> list disk

DISK ###  Status
--------  ---------------
DISK 0    Invalid

DISKPART> select disk 0
DISKPART> select partition

Partition ###  TYPE     
-------------  --------------
Partition 1    Dynamic Data
Partition 2    Dynamic Data
Partition 3    Dynamic Data
Partition 4    Primary        <- I think I put linux here
```

Any idea whats happening? Or how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: How big is your HDD and did you not add an swap?

Comment: If I am not mistaken you are limited to 4 dynamic partitions.  In the future don't ignore warning messages.  Furthermore if you cannot give us exact error messages its hard for us to help you.

Comment: Any success, how did you solve the problem? I ran into the same issue and it seems like "bootrec /fixboot" (running it off a windows 7 DVD) doesn't seem to see any windows installation.

Comment: I didn't solve it. I did a back up, formatted the disk and installed linux again

Answer (score 2):

Repair Windows 7 bootloader using the DVD, here are the [instructions](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/ss/windows-7-startup-repair_7.htm).

Once you get into windows, use

> diskmgmt.msc

and figure out what you did to your partitions

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I have to mention that your question is unclear on some details.

> After google for a while I found the diskpart command, it gives me
>   this info:

How exactly did you use the "diskpart command" if your computer was already not booting? It's a command-line utility in Windows, so how can you use it when it's not booting?

Anyway, from your info it seems like you might have a conflict with the primary partition and who gets to use it. Windows must be installed on a primary partition; Linux does not have to be. So if it's true that your HDD has only 1 primary partition, and the Linux installation is on that one, then that would explain why Windows is not booting. I don't understand how such a situation could even occur unless you installed Linux over Windows and wiped out Windows in the process... But you did say that you installed it on the newly created partition, so that would mean that you must've placed it on a logical partition (which is okay).

To repair the situation, probably HackToHell's solution is appropriate. But check out this article about dealing with partitions if you want to set up a dual boot: 
http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/dual_boot.html 
It's not exactly like what you were trying to accomplish, but it does explain the basic ideas behind partitioning pretty clearly and succinctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with Linux but I know how to set the windows back. If you have the backup disk of windows 7 then it's quite easy. Just restore the data using your backup image disk. Or you can try to restore your windows to a restore point. I hope it will work for you.